# How to use Kafka Connect to source .csv files from S3 bucket?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

From what I understand, S3 source connector only works with objects that were uploaded with S3 sink connector. I also know there's a spooldir connector to read .csv files from a local directory.

But what do I use to read .csv files from an S3 bucket? Or is this impractical?

Comment: You could use Spark or Nifi

Comment: use Kafka Connect to source directly from S3. read more here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3-source/index.html

Comment: I ended up just writing a custom Kafka Connect connector.

Comment: @atkayla would be cool if you will share that connector. it's highly searchable...

Comment: Is the S3SourceConnector is unable to read CSV files from S3 bucket ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but for those who are looking for an answer you can use FilePulse Source Connector. It supports reading CSV files from S3 bucket as well as other cloud suppliers.

> Connect FilePulse is a multipurpose, scalable and reliable, Kafka Connector that makes it easy to parse, transform and stream any file, in **any format**, into Apache Kafka™. It provides capabilities for reading files from: local-filesystem, **Amazon S3**, Azure Storage and Google Cloud Storage.

[source](https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse)