# Kafka Connect SpooldirCsv connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I am trying to use the Confluent's SpoolDirCSVSource connector to read files from a directory and send to MSK. Works fine  on my local. But now I need to source it  from S3 bucket . Is there no way I can use this connector  to do this  ? Or is there some other connector which does this ? The input.path parameter works only with local directories I think. Any pointer in right direction to the correct connector or modifying the SpoolDirCSV connector would be appreciated.

I know this question is old , something similar. But I am curious to know if this functionality is still absent (I can be wrong).

[How to use Kafka Connect to source .csv files from S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307439/how-to-use-kafka-connect-to-source-csv-files-from-s3-bucket)

This is the exact error when the connector is deployed to cloud

*There is an issue with the connector
Code: InvalidInput.InvalidConnectorConfiguration
Message: The connector configuration is invalid. Message: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s): Invalid value File 's3:/mytestbucketak/input' is not an absolute path. for configuration input.path Invalid value File 's3:/mytestbucketak/error' is not an absolute path. for configuration error.path*

Answer (score 1):

That connector can only read from local filesystem, not S3.

Confluent has a specific **S3 Source** Connector, or as linked, FilePulse Connector also exists.

Comment: When you say specific, it means it can read from S3 only those files which were written to S3 by another confluent connector right ?

Comment: No. The [Generalized Source](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-source/current/generalized/overview.html) is different from the "Backup and Restore" (Sink / Source pair) connector

Comment: I am going the Filepulse route for now. The generalized source connector you mentioned has the limitation : "As long as the files are in any of the supported formats (for example, JSON, Avro and Byte Array) the connector will be able to read them." I need to read csv files. Its really surprising that Confluent did not develop a connector from any cloud directly. May be its in works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. CSV files are still "bytes",so that might still work... Adding support for "any cloud" is not really possible since each use different SDK, which each have different CVE vulnerabilities, and would be a nonstop maintenance effort